# Given density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 8xy$ determine the distribution of the variable $\frac{X}{Y}$. Then tell if this variable independent of $Y$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, density-function

The two-dimensional random vector $(X, Y)$ has a distribution with joint density:
$$g(x,y) = 8xy  \ \text{  for:  } 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1$$

Determine the distribution of the variable $\frac{X}{Y}$. Is this variable independent of $Y$?

I don't know how to do that. I've calculated PDFs:

- $f_X(x) = 4x(1 - x^2)$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $0$ else,
- $f_Y(y) = 4y^3$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $0$ else.

Also I calculated $Cov(X, Y) = \frac{56}{25}$, $Var(X) = \frac{11}{225}$, $Var(Y) = \frac{2}{75}$.

I know that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent since: $f_{X,Y} (x,y) \neq f_X(x) \cdot f_Y(y)$

However, I don't know how to answer the question.

Edit:

For: $f_X(x)$ I did: $\int_x^1 8xy \ dx$

For: $f_Y(y)$ I did: $\int_0^y 8xy \ dx$

For: $Cov(X,Y)$ I did: $E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$, therefore:

- for: $E(XY)$ I did: $\int_0^1 \int_0^y xy \cdot 8xy \ dx dy $
- for: $E(X)$ I did: $\int_0^1 x \cdot 4x(1-x^2) \ dx$
- for: $E(Y)$ I did: $\int_0^1 y \cdot 4y^3 \ dy$

For $Var(X)$ I did: $\int_0^1 \left(x - \frac{8}{15} \right)^2 \cdot 4x(1 - x^2) \ dx$

For $Var(Y)$ I did: $\int_0^1 \left(y - \frac{4}{5} \right)^2 \cdot 4y^3 \ dy$

Comment: Provided your calculation of the covariance is right there's nothing more to do as independency implies vanishing covariance.

Comment: In order to determine the distribution of $X/Y$, you could use the steps outlined under "Products and quotients of independent random variables" in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function

Comment: btw your pdf of $X$ is wrong; you integrated from $0$ to $1$ instead of $x$ to $1$: $f_X(x) = \int_x^1 8xy \ dy = 4x(1 - x^2)$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0$ elsewhere

Comment: @0XLR thank you! I integrated pdf of $Y$ from $0$ to $y$. Is that ok?

Comment: @mathman12 that's fine of course

Comment: @0XLR because of the error that you have pointed out I got anxious about my understanding of other integrals. Therefore I edited my post. Could you check if they are ok? I mean, just the ideas - I am sure that the results are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes $U = X/Y$ and $V = Y$ are in fact independent. To see this do a multivariate pdf transformation from $(X, Y)$ to $(U, V)$.

Let $T : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be $T(x, y) = \begin{cases} (x/y, y) &y \neq 0 \\ 0 &y = 0 \end{cases}$. $(X, Y)$'s support $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 \leq x \leq y \leq 1\}$ is mapped almost everywhere to $\{(u, v) \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 \leq u \leq 1, 0 \leq v \leq 1\} = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ which must be $(U, V)$'s support. The inverse of $T$ almost everywhere is $T^{-1} : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, $T^{-1}(u, v) = (uv, v)$ with Jacobian $JT^{-1}(u, v) = \begin{pmatrix} v &u \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$. So the pdf of $(U, V)$ is
$$
f_{U, V}(u, v) = f_{X, Y}(T^{-1}(u, v))\big|JT^{-1}(u, v)\big| = 8uv^3 \text{ for } (u, v) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]
$$ and $0$ elsewhere.

You can easily note that $U, V$ are independent as their joint support is rectangular and their pdf is separable. And finally, deriving the pdf of $U = X/Y$ is straightforward from the above.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you! Will post the pdf of $U = X/Y$ in a minute.

Comment: $f_U(u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{U, V}(u, v) \ dv = \int_{0}^{1} 8uv^3 \ dv  = 8u \int_{0}^{1} v^3 \ dv = 8u \left( \frac{v^4}{4} \Big|^1_0 \right) = 2u$ for $u \in [0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere. Is that correct? @0XLR